# Add Authorization Header in Apache Nifi InvokeHTTP Processor

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, apache-nifi

In my dataflow configured in Apache Nifi, I have an API that requires Authorization header (bearer token) to invoke with a GET request.
I'm trying to configure the **InvokeHTTP processor** for this, but it doesn't support Authorization headers by default.

How can I add the Authorization header (maybe as an Attribute) into the GET request using Nifi's InvokeHttp processor?

Answer (score 2):

You can add as many "dynamic properties" to the processor config as you like and they will be passed as HTTP headers on the request. You can populate the token via parameter or general Expression Language in the property value, but be aware that if using variables/parameters, you won't be able to use sensitive parameters because those must be referenced exactly rather than combined, and in this case you'll need to prepend the value with `Bearer` . There is [an open ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7310) to make authorization header usage (OAuth2 specifically) easier with this processor.

Comment: There's an example showing this here: https://pierrevillard.com/2017/01/31/nifi-and-oauth-2-0-to-request-wordpress-api/ (search for "And I add a property to specify my access token as a header property:"). Property is "Authorization" and value is "Bearer: ${access_token}" where access_token prop came from a previous EvaluateJsonPath step.

Comment: it is works in  version  1.22, 1.23 too, we just need to add Authorization (this automatically puted in to header of GET-request) attribute in InvokeHTTP block and substitute token  **Authorization**: `Bearer ${token_attribute_from_EvaluateJsonPath}`